# How do I change my default shell to use ZSH in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, shell, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make Bash my default shell on Ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/questions/46748/how-do-i-make-bash-my-default-shell-on-ubuntu)

I want to change my default shell in Ubuntu to ZSH. What's the command to do this?

Comment: *zsh* is a shell, not a terminal.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use

```
chsh -s $(which zsh)
```

Unlike `adduser` or `useradd` or editing `/etc/passwd`, this will allow you to change your shell without having root rights.

Answer (score 0):

hum ... zsh is a shell, not a terminal.

An alternative answer to MrStatic's is using change the default shell with `chsh`, this can be done for your account without any root privileges.

Answer (score -1):

You would have to edit your `/etc/passwd`

Use the `vipw` command and change the shell next to the user you want to change. To make it the default for all new users `useradd -D -s /bin/bash`