# Arrows don't work in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, terminal, character-encoding

I'm using Ubuntu 12.xx When I'm in a shell (xterm or gnome terminal) and I press the UP arrow, the terminal prints "^]]A" instead of fetching the last used command like it normally does.

How can I restore the old functionality?

Comment: It seems that you are not using bash as the shell... Try [changing the dafault shell to bash](http://superuser.com/questions/46748/how-do-i-make-bash-my-default-shell-on-ubuntu).

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
passwd -e yourlogin
```

then change your default shell by typing it's full path.

I prefer to use tcsh instead just as a suggestion.